# How to skip a function in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I need to skip mollom verification if the users on a site have more then X points. Does anyone knows if it is possible to right a module that skips mollom_form_alter ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't skip the mollom_form_alter call, to do that you would need to alter the mollom module itself, What you can do, howerver, is to alter the form after mollom, undoing whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip a form alter call, however you can create your own form alter that "triggers" mollom based on the number of points that the user has.